# Unable to Clear 'Search' results

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to clear Search results when a new query is entered in the websites search bar.
For example I am developing a TV search website, if I search 'Friends' a list of results will display however if I enter a new query the results will not clear and print at the bottom of the previous list of results.

I have tried features such as `resultList.innerHTML = '';`

Here is some of my JavaScript:

```js
fetch(`https: //api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${TVShow}`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    for (const value of data) {
      document.querySelector(".TVShowInfo").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        `<div id="TVShow">
           <center>
             <h1>${value.show.name}</h1>
           </center>
         </div>`);
    }
  })
```

```html
<div class="searchBox">
  <input id="TVShowName" type="TV show information" placeholder="Search for a TV show..." />
  <button id="search">Search</button>
</div>
<div class="TVShowInfo"></div>
```

Comment: I have been stuck for quite awhile, I'm fairly new to JavaScript-- if you require anymore code or details please let me know.

Comment: What’s “resultList”? Where do you clear anything in the posted code?

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: Hi, Dave: I've tryied elements such as "resultList.innerHTML = '';" and other methods to attempt to clear my search resluts, sorry If i posted this poory; I was looking for any help / a point in the right direction to be able to clear my resluts: when a user makes a quiry it will print "value.show.name" I would like to know how I would then clear the reslut of "value.show.name" when I enter a new search reslut in my seach bar: If i should add all my code lmk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - just replace the innerHTML instead of insertAdjacentHTML.

I also changed the ID to class and removed the deprecated center

```js
document.querySelector(".TVShowInfo").innerHTML = data
  .map(({show}) => `<div class="TVShow"><h1>${show.name}</h1></div>`).join('<br/>');
```

```css
.TVShow { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div class="TVShowInfo"></div>
<script>
const data = [{"score":0.9089527,"show":{"id":431,"url":"https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/431/friends","name":"Friends","type":"Scripted","language":"English","genres":["Comedy","Romance"],"status":"Ended","runtime":30,"averageRuntime":30,"premiered":"1994-09-22","ended":"2004-05-06","officialSite":null,"schedule":{"time":"20:00","days":["Thursday"]},"rating":{"average":8.5},"weight":98,"network":{"id":1,"name":"NBC","country":{"name":"United States","code":"US","timezone":"America/New_York"},"officialSite":"https://www.nbc.com/"},"webChannel":null,"dvdCountry":null,"externals":{"tvrage":3616,"thetvdb":79168,"imdb":"tt0108778"},"image":{"medium":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/41/104550.jpg","original":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/41/104550.jpg"},"summary":"<p>Six young (20-something) people from New York City (Manhattan), on their own and struggling to survive in the real world, find the companionship, comfort and support they get from each other to be the perfect antidote to the pressures of life.</p><p>This average group of buddies goes through massive mayhem, family trouble, past and future romances, fights, laughs, tears and surprises as they learn what it really means to be a friend.</p>","updated":1641068842,"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/431"},"previousepisode":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/40881"}}}},{"score":0.8193341,"show":{"id":46948,"url":"https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/46948/friends","name":"Friends","type":"Scripted","language":"English","genres":["Drama","Comedy"],"status":"Ended","runtime":60,"averageRuntime":60,"premiered":"1979-03-25","ended":"1979-04-22","officialSite":null,"schedule":{"time":"","days":["Sunday"]},"rating":{"average":null},"weight":21,"network":{"id":3,"name":"ABC","country":{"name":"United States","code":"US","timezone":"America/New_York"},"officialSite":"https://"+"abc.com/"},"webChannel":null,"dvdCountry":null,"externals":{"tvrage":null,"thetvdb":76973,"imdb":"tt0078615"},"image":null,"summary":"A comedy-drama series as seen through the eyes of three 11-year-old children from different backgrounds with episodes focusing upon the trials and tribulations of adolescence, and involved subjects such as dating, family, school, growing pains and friendship.","updated":1585366201,"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/46948"},"previousepisode":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/1824845"}}}},{"score":0.8159303,"show":{"id":30774,"url":"https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/30774/friends","name":"Friends","type":"Scripted","language":"Japanese","genres":["Drama","Romance"],"status":"Ended","runtime":65,"averageRuntime":65,"premiered":"2002-02-04","ended":"2002-02-05","officialSite":"http://www.tbs.co.jp/friends21/","schedule":{"time":"21:00","days":["Monday","Tuesday"]},"rating":{"average":null},"weight":19,"network":{"id":159,"name":"TBS","country":{"name":"Japan","code":"JP","timezone":"Asia/Tokyo"},"officialSite":"https://www.tbs.co.jp/"},"webChannel":null,"dvdCountry":null,"externals":{"tvrage":null,"thetvdb":99721,"imdb":"tt0315608"},"image":{"medium":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/122/305714.jpg","original":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/122/305714.jpg"},"summary":"<p>Left alone on a trip to Hong Kong, Tomoko finds herself the victim of a purse-snatching. The police arrest the man she points out, but it turns out to be the wrong person: a young Korean man named Ji Hoon. Despite his anger and humiliation, he takes her out to dinner since she has lost all her money, and in return, she agrees to model for his amateur film. What follows is a magical and romantic two days. Upon returning to their respective countries, Tomoko must return to her nine-to-five job and Ji Hoon must resume studying to join the family business rather than pursuing his dream of becoming a film director. But soon the two begin to email each other and rekindle their relationship despite the distance and obstacles between them. Marking the very first time in television history that a drama has been co-produced between Japan and South Korea, the story shows us that love has no borders.</p>","updated":1635779876,"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/30774"},"previousepisode":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/1260315"}}}},{"score":0.807294,"show":{"id":53703,"url":"https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/53703/friends","name":"Friends","type":"Variety","language":"Korean","genres":[],"status":"Ended","runtime":90,"averageRuntime":90,"premiered":"2021-02-17","ended":"2021-05-12","officialSite":"http://m.ichannela.com/program/menu/prm_menu2_mob.do?pgm_contents=050078&type=02&menuIndex=2&seqIndex=0&realCateCode=05007801&boardType=null&boardId=null&cateName=%ED%94%84%EB%A1%9C%EA%B7%B8%EB%9E%A8%20%EC%86%8C%EA%B0%9C","schedule":{"time":"21:10","days":["Wednesday"]},"rating":{"average":null},"weight":16,"network":{"id":538,"name":"Channel A","country":{"name":"Korea, Republic of","code":"KR","timezone":"Asia/Seoul"},"officialSite":null},"webChannel":null,"dvdCountry":null,"externals":{"tvrage":null,"thetvdb":396947,"imdb":null},"image":{"medium":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/297/743857.jpg","original":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/297/743857.jpg"},"summary":"<p>Reuniting old friends and introducing new acquaintances, cast members from Heart Signal 2 &amp; 3 are back in a brand new variety series and sparks are sure to fly! Invited to spend a very special winter at Signal House, relationships between Oh Young Joo, Jung Jae Ho, Kim Do Gyun, Kim Jang Mi, Lee Ga Heun, Park Ji Hyun, Seo Min Jae, and Jung Eui Dong are sure to blossom. But which relationships will remain friendly and which will blossom into love? Follow the members through their daily lives and find out! Hosted by Super Junior's Kim Hee Chul and Shindong, Oh My Girl's Seunghee, and Lee Sang Min.</p>","updated":1668808710,"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/53703"},"previousepisode":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/2090402"}}}},{"score":0.69863015,"show":{"id":47182,"url":"https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/47182/smiling-friends","name":"Smiling Friends","type":"Animation","language":"English","genres":["Comedy"],"status":"Running","runtime":15,"averageRuntime":15,"premiered":"2020-04-01","ended":null,"officialSite":"http://www.adultswim.com/videos/smiling-friends","schedule":{"time":"","days":["Sunday"]},"rating":{"average":null},"weight":91,"network":{"id":10,"name":"Adult Swim","country":{"name":"United States","code":"US","timezone":"America/New_York"},"officialSite":null},"webChannel":null,"dvdCountry":null,"externals":{"tvrage":null,"thetvdb":379403,"imdb":"tt12074628"},"image":{"medium":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/251/628722.jpg","original":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/251/628722.jpg"},"summary":"<p>A small company dedicated to bringing happiness to the world receives a simple request to help a woman's unhappy son smile again, but the job turns out to be more complicated than it seems.</p>","updated":1659887321,"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/47182"},"previousepisode":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/2365336"}}}},{"score":0.6878882,"show":{"id":20474,"url":"https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/20474/angels-friends","name":"Angel's Friends","type":"Animation","language":"Italian","genres":["Adventure","Children","Fantasy"],"status":"Ended","runtime":15,"averageRuntime":15,"premiered":"2009-10-12","ended":"2012-04-29","officialSite":"http://www.angelsfriends.it","schedule":{"time":"","days":["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]},"rating":{"average":null},"weight":69,"network":{"id":1272,"name":"Italia 1","country":{"name":"Italy","code":"IT","timezone":"Europe/Rome"},"officialSite":null},"webChannel":null,"dvdCountry":null,"externals":{"tvrage":null,"thetvdb":264933,"imdb":"tt1731708"},"image":{"medium":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/72/180985.jpg","original":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/72/180985.jpg"},"summary":"<p>Special school for the Angels is full of secrets! What happens if at the same table will be angels and devils? Raf, Uri, Sweet and Mickey - a company of angels. But to become a real team, they do not have a single person. Friends leave their homes and go down to the Earth in the \"Golden School\". They need to get the last \"missing percentage\", which will make their guardian angels at 100%. Their mission is to accompany selected earthlings in their daily adventures...</p>","updated":1573079445,"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/20474"},"previousepisode":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/1382408"}}}},{"score":0.68657506,"show":{"id":65357,"url":"https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/65357/only-friends","name":"Only Friends","type":"Scripted","language":"Thai","genres":["Drama","Romance"],"status":"In Development","runtime":null,"averageRuntime":null,"premiered":null,"ended":null,"officialSite":"https://www.gmm-tv.com/home/","schedule":{"time":"","days":[]},"rating":{"average":null},"weight":66,"network":{"id":1095,"name":"GMM25","country":{"name":"Thailand","code":"TH","timezone":"Asia/Bangkok"},"officialSite":null},"webChannel":null,"dvdCountry":null,"externals":{"tvrage":null,"thetvdb":null,"imdb":null},"image":{"medium":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/431/1079406.jpg","original":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/431/1079406.jpg"},"summary":null,"updated":1669158203,"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/65357"}}}},{"score":0.6837748,"show":{"id":11090,"url":"https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/11090/mutual-friends","name":"Mutual Friends","type":"Scripted","language":"English","genres":["Drama","Comedy"],"status":"Ended","runtime":60,"averageRuntime":60,"premiered":"2008-08-26","ended":"2008-09-30","officialSite":"http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00d98sz","schedule":{"time":"21:00","days":["Tuesday"]},"rating":{"average":null},"weight":65,"network":{"id":12,"name":"BBC One","country":{"name":"United Kingdom","code":"GB","timezone":"Europe/London"},"officialSite":"https://www.bbc.co.uk/bbcone"},"webChannel":null,"dvdCountry":null,"externals":{"tvrage":18729,"thetvdb":82899,"imdb":"tt1062325"},"image":{"medium":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/37/93077.jpg","original":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/37/93077.jpg"},"summary":"<p>Martin has two best friends, Patrick and Carl, who couldn't be more different. One is an irresponsible, unreliable, feckless womaniser and the other is dead. Guess which one slept with his wife?Martin Grantham is happily married to Jen. They have a son Dan, a nice house, the works. One day his best friend Carl throws himself under a train, setting off a disastrous sequence of events that will change Martin's life forever…Into this mess steps Patrick, a friend from way back. Patrick is everything Martin is not – glib, self-confident, popular and pathologically immature. He's the last person Martin needs in his life right now. Or is he?</p>","updated":1555974558,"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/11090"},"previousepisode":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/555093"}}}},{"score":0.68103445,"show":{"id":7403,"url":"https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/7403/battlefield-friends","name":"Battlefield Friends","type":"Animation","language":"English","genres":["Comedy","Adventure"],"status":"Ended","runtime":3,"averageRuntime":3,"premiered":"2012-03-20","ended":"2016-08-20","officialSite":"https://www.youtube.com/show/battlefieldfriends","schedule":{"time":"","days":[]},"rating":{"average":null},"weight":56,"network":null,"webChannel":{"id":21,"name":"YouTube","country":null,"officialSite":"https://www.youtube.com"},"dvdCountry":null,"externals":{"tvrage":null,"thetvdb":262928,"imdb":"tt2354667"},"image":{"medium":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/27/68210.jpg","original":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/27/68210.jpg"},"summary":"<p><b>Battlefield Friends</b> is a series of animated shorts set in the game world of Battlefield 3 and Battlefield 4. It chronicles the misadventures of four friends and squadmembers, embodying the four soldier classes available in the games. The series often comically attacks/parodies player trends and game mechanics, such as spawnkilling, buggy bipods, Closet Colonels, etc.</p><p>The series follows four players-a medic, an engineer, a sniper, and a noob. The series incorporates surreal humor mixed with cartoon comedy gags.</p>","updated":1657875759,"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/7403"},"previousepisode":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/903483"}}}},{"score":0.6768293,"show":{"id":45922,"url":"https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/45922/graceful-friends","name":"Graceful Friends","type":"Scripted","language":"Korean","genres":["Drama","Crime","Mystery"],"status":"Ended","runtime":80,"averageRuntime":80,"premiered":"2020-07-10","ended":"2020-09-05","officialSite":"http://tv.jtbc.joins.com/gracefulfriends","schedule":{"time":"22:50","days":["Friday","Saturday"]},"rating":{"average":null},"weight":55,"network":{"id":268,"name":"jTBC","country":{"name":"Korea, Republic of","code":"KR","timezone":"Asia/Seoul"},"officialSite":null},"webChannel":null,"dvdCountry":null,"externals":{"tvrage":null,"thetvdb":378806,"imdb":"tt12531492"},"image":{"medium":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/262/655331.jpg","original":"https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/262/655331.jpg"},"summary":"<p><b>Graceful Friends</b> is a mystery drama about a murder that occurs in a new town inhabited by married couples in their 40s and follows the story of a group of middle-aged men after their peaceful everyday lives are disrupted.</p>","updated":1655183561,"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/45922"},"previousepisode":{"href":"https://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/1914740"}}}}]
    </script>
```

Comment: I changed the ID to class and removed the deprecated center

Comment: Thank you so much! Ik it sounds silly but I've been stuck for ages! Cheers again! :D

Answer (score 0):

just set the innerHtml to blank

```
<body>

  <div class="searchBox">
    <input id="TVShowName" type="search" placeholder="Search for a TV show..." />
    <button id="search">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div class="TVShowInfo"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>

    const searchInput = document.getElementById("TVShowName");
    const contentArea = document.querySelector(".TVShowInfo");
    function searchShow(TVShow) {
      fetch(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${TVShow}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          contentArea.innerHTML = "";
          for (const value of data) {
            contentArea.insertAdjacentHTML(
              "beforeend",
              `
            <div id="TVShow">
            <center>
            <h1>${value.show.name}</h1>
          
            </center>
          </div>`
            );
            // searchInput.value = "";
          }
        });
    }

    document.getElementById("search").onclick = function (e) {
      searchShow(searchInput.value);
    };


  </script>

</body>
```